# Failed to install 'cordova-admob-sdk'

Tags: cordova, parse-android-sdk, cordova-admob, cordova6.4.0

```
$ cordova platform add android --nofetch
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
        Path: platforms\android
        Package: com.weyaltech.dailynews
        Name: Daily_News
        Activity: MainActivity
        Android target: android-26
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Android project created with cordova-android@6.4.0
Installing "cordova-admob-sdk" for android
Failed to install 'cordova-admob-sdk': Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Nik Weyal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:238:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:407:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
```

Comment: Please elaborate more about cordova version, android version and plugin details

Comment: sources;android-26 | 1 | Sources for Android 26
  sources;android-27 | 1 | Sources for Android 27
  sources;android-28| 1| Sources for Android 28

Comment: $ cordova platform version android
Installed platforms:
  android 6.4.0
Available platforms:
  blackberry10 ~3.8.0 (deprecated)
  browser ~5.0.0
  ios ~4.5.1
  osx ~4.0.1
  ubuntu ~4.3.4 (deprecated)
  webos ~3.7.0
  windows ~5.0.0
  www ^3.12.0

Comment: $ cordova -v
7.1.0